# Push 2 kind of Id in array

Tags: json, mongodb, push

Good day,
I've been studying json and mongoDB this past few months and  I'm trying to push my user's ID and my product ID into my order's array. but I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

this is the part of the code that is having a problem.

```
let isUserIdPush = await User.findById(data.userId).then(user => {
    user.usersOrder.push({productId : data.productId});

    return user.save().then((user, error) => {
        if(error){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    })
})
```

I check my models and there is nothing wrong with it and I guess that my productId is the fault

edit:
I remove the models.

Comment: Your questions sounds like you want us to do your homework for you - please ask a short and specific question instead

Comment: thank you for comments, I've updated my post to my specific question

Comment: I already found a solution to my problem I remove "User.findById(data.userId).then" now I have no error but when I send it in postman no array is pushed.